# Using FFT as a channeliser

Tags: fft, dft, filter-bank

This [article](http://www.pentek.com/tutorials/15_4/digdown.cfm) mentions that the DFT/FFT can be used as a channeliser in a similar way to a filterbank. I get how the DFT filters into spectral bins, but its output is in the frequency domain, i.e. Fourier coefficients, nolonger in the time domain, so either I'm missing something or they've neglected to mention that DFT filterbank output would need to be transformed back to the time domain to function like an actual filterbank. Can someone shed light on this?

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest you take a look at the [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform).

Let say you use $N$-point FFT, then you filterbank has $N/2$ filters (assuming real signal). Usually, you divide your signal into $K$ segments, each $N$ samples long (could be overlapping) and apply the FFT to each segment. Every time you apply the FFT you get a single sample for each filter. Therefore your filterbank has $N/2$ filters with $K$ samples.

Answer (score 0):

An FFT of an appropriate length can be used as a channelizer if the system doesn't need the actual time domain signals within each channel from the filter bank, but rather just a measure or estimate over a given time period of the magnitude and/or phase of the signal within each channel.  Often (but not always) this is all that is needed for certain multi-channel detection and/or demodulation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no extra transform to get back into the time domain.  Try not to get caught up in the time vs. frequency domain thought process. Use of the fft provides a resource efficient way to implement a bank of bandpass filters. You don't have to use an fft, but you'd require more multiply/add operations without it. The Fred Harris book "Multirate Signal Processing" does a pretty good job of explaining how one arrives at the FFT implementation.